# Solving a linear equation in one variable

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, linear-algebra

What would be the most efficient algorithm to solve a linear equation in one variable given as a string input to a function? For example, for input string:

> "x + 9 – 2 - 4 + x = – x + 5 – 1 + 3 – x"

The output should be 1.

I am considering using a stack and pushing each string token onto it as I encounter spaces in the string. If the input was in polish notation then it would have been easier to pop numbers off the stack to get to a result, but I am not sure what approach to take here.

It is an interview question.

Comment: A possible would be to use Regex to parse the string and split it up.

Comment: And Then you would need to go through the split up chunks and determine what they are. first find variables then numbers, or vice versa obviously you would need to determine plus minus and the like as well. then compute the output based on what you find, it is simple arithmetic from there.

Comment: just put x'ses on left, number on right side of equation. Divide both sites by multiplier of X and voila;)

Comment: You can tokenize the string (considering starting x as +x) into Vector<char,char> leftHand and Vector<char,char> rightHand ~ <sign,literal> .. then unify numerals on one side, and symbols on the other side, then solve it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solving the linear equation is (I hope) extremely easy for you once you've worked out the coefficients `a` and `b` in the equation `a * x + b = 0`.

So, the difficult part of the problem is parsing the expression and "evaluating" it to find the coefficients. Your example expression is extremely simple, it uses only the operators unary `-`, binary `-`, binary `+`. And `=`, which you could handle specially.

It is not clear from the question whether the solution should also handle expressions involving binary `*` and `/`, or parentheses. I'm wondering whether the interview question is intended:

- to make you write some simple code, or
- to make you ask what the real scope of the problem is before you write anything.

Both are important skills :-)

It could even be that the question is intended:

- to separate those with lots of experience writing parsers (who will solve it as fast as they can write/type) from those with none (who might struggle to solve it at all within a few minutes, at least without some hints).

Anyway, to allow for future more complicated requirements, there are two common approaches to parsing arithmetic expressions: recursive descent or Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm. You can look these up, and if you only need the simple expressions in version 1.0 then you can use a simplified form of Dijkstra's algorithm. Then once you've parsed the expression, you need to evaluate it: use values that are linear expressions in `x` and interpret `=` as an operator with lowest possible precedence that means "subtract". The result is a linear expression in `x` that is equal to `0`.

If you don't need complicated expressions then you can evaluate that simple example pretty much directly from left-to-right once you've tokenised it[*]:

```
x
x + 9
// set the "we've found minus sign" bit to negate the first thing that follows
x + 7 // and clear the negative bit
x + 3
2 * x + 3
// set the "we've found the equals sign" bit to negate everything that follows
3 * x + 3
3 * x - 2
3 * x - 1
3 * x - 4
4 * x - 4
```

Finally, solve `a * x + b = 0` as `x = - b/a`.

[*] example tokenisation code, in Python:

```
acc = None
for idx, ch in enumerate(input):
    if ch in '1234567890':
        if acc is None: acc = 0
        acc = 10 * acc + int(ch)
        continue
    if acc != None:
        yield acc
        acc = None
    if ch in '+-=x':
        yield ch
    elif ch == ' ':
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError('illegal character "%s" at %d' % (ch, idx))
```

Alternative example tokenisation code, also in Python, assuming there will always be spaces between tokens as in the example. This leaves token validation to the parser:

```
return input.split()
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. If I was interviewing you for this I'd be concerned if you assumed multiplying and dividing when it isn't used in the example, I guess you would ask this though.  I would also expect an experienced programmer to mention the spaces because they make splitting the equation without regexp etc possible.  Of course it makes sense to ask if they can be relied on.  If it's only using +/-/= and the spaces are reliable then you as you say can just work from left to right, adding all the constants together and counting the xs.

Comment: @Will: indeed, I'd ask before doing anything more complicated, but if I didn't ask I'd half-expect to finish the code and then be asked to modify it. Actually I probably *wouldn't* make an issue of the spaces, because tokenising that example is easy with or without them. A token is either a sequence of digits (maximal munch) or a single character. Discard space "tokens" since all they do is separate. In Python or C++ with Boost I might want to use a library function to tokenise by just splitting on whitespace, in which case I'd ask first. I wouldn't use regexes for this in either language.

Answer (score 1):

ok some simple psuedo code that you could use to solve this problem

```
 function(stinrgToParse){
      arrayoftokens = stringToParse.match(RegexMatching);
      foreach(arrayoftokens as token)
      {
         //now step through the tokens and determine what they are
         //and store the neccesary information.
      }
      //Use the above information to do the arithmetic.
      //count the number of times a variable appears positive and negative
      //do the arithmetic.
      //add up the numbers both positive and negative. 
      //return the result.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to parse the string, to identify the various tokens (numbers, variables and operators), so that an expression tree can be formed by giving operator proper precedences.

Regular expressions can help, but that's not the only method (grammar parsers like boost::spirit are good too, and you can even run your own: its all a "find and recourse").

The tree can then be manipulated reducing the nodes executing those operation that deals with constants and by grouping variables related operations, executing them accordingly.

This goes on recursively until you remain with a variable related node and a constant node.

At the point the solution is calculated trivially.

They are basically the same principles that leads to the production of an interpreter or a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
from operator import add, sub
def ab(expr):
    a, b, op = 0, 0, add
    for t in expr.split():
        if   t == '+': op = add
        elif t == '-': op = sub
        elif t == 'x': a = op(a, 1)
        else         : b = op(b, int(t))
    return a, b
```

Given an expression like `1 + x - 2 - x...` this converts it to a canonical form `ax+b` and returns a pair of coefficients `(a,b)`.

Now, let's obtain the coefficients from both parts of the equation:

```
le, ri = equation.split('=')    
a1, b1 = ab(le)
a2, b2 = ab(ri)
```

and finally solve the trivial equation `a1*x + b1 = a2*x + b2`:

```
x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2)
```

Of course, this only solves this particular example, without operator precedence or parentheses. To support the latter you'll need a parser, presumable a recursive descent one, which would be simper to code by hand.